# An automorphism acting on the sheaf of differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to do the following problem, taken from Iitaka's "Algebraic Geometry".

Let C be a smooth, geometrically connected curve of genus g over a field k. Assume that $g \geq 2$. If $f \in Aut(C)$ satisfies that $f^\ast w = w$ for all $w \in \Omega^1_{C/k}$, show that $f=id$.

I have no idea so far, so any hint would be nice (or solution).

Comment: Is it not the case (in the non-hyperelliptic case) that $f$ leaves the canonical curve in $\mathbb P^{g-1}$ pointwise fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following method works, but for the case when C is non-hyperelliptic, consider the following:
The canonical map $g:C \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{g-1}_k$ is a closed immersion since C is not hyperelliptic, so assume that $f \in Aut(C)$ acts as the identity on $\Omega^1_{C/k}$. Then we have a commutative diagram 
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
C @>{g}>> \mathbb{P}^{g-1}_k;\\
@VfVV @VidVV \\
C @>{g}>> \mathbb{P}^{g-1}_k;
\end{CD}.$$

This gives us $g= g \circ f$, and since g is a monomorphism (closed immersion) we get that $f=id_C$. However, I am a bit unsure if this is true, since the result seem a bit too strong and I would like people to tell me if it is wrong, so don't trust me all too much!

Comment: So if anyone has the time, I'd be very happy if someone could say if my reasoning breaks down or not, and in that case where.

Comment: I think the key point is that any automorphism of the canonical embedding must be induced by a linear automorphism of $\mathbb P^{g-1}$, so having the identity on $g(C)$ means that we have the identity on $C$. I guess the hyperelliptic case takes a bit of analysis, taking into account the hyperelliptic involution.

Comment: Ted Shifrin: You are probably right. Please tell me if you think my reasoning breaks down here for the non-hyperelliptic case.

Comment: In the hyperelliptic case, the canonical curve is the rational normal curve in $\mathbb P^{g-1}$ and the mapping factors through the $2:1$ projection to $\mathbb P^1$. Indeed, the image is invariant under the hyperelliptic involution $\iota$, but $\iota^*\omega = -\omega$ for any $\omega\in H^0(C,\Omega^1)$, so it should follow that the only automorphism $f=\text{id}$ is the only option.

Comment: Ted Shifrin: Okay, thanks for that case. Does the posted answer work for the non-hyperelliptic?